# property 'enqueueSetState' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have a problem with my React app:
*cannot read property 'enqueueSetState' of undefined*
i have 2 components:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Display from '../Display/Display.js';

class Button extends Component {
  clicked(e){
    Display.prototype.clicked(e);
  };
render() {
return (
  <div className="calculator__button" onClick={() => this.clicked(this.props.value)}>
    {this.props.value}
  </div>
);
}
}

export default Button;
```

and

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Display.css';

class Display extends Component {
  constructor () {
     super();
     this.clicked = this.clicked.bind(this);
     this.state = {
        text : 0
     };
  }
  clicked = () => {
    this.setState({
      text : this.state.text + 1
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="calculator__display">
        {this.state.text}
      </div>
    );
  } 
}

export default Display;
```

I want to change Display state after clicking on Button component.
I tryed to bind this to setState and to use arrow function as a callback but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You are just importing the class Display, but this is not a reference to a component that is currently being displayed - just a class definition.

In order to have this connection you need to make some adjustments. I am not sure exactly what setup you want (either a common parent - or Display is a parent to Button?).

If Display is parent:

The render method needs to show the button:

```
render() {
return (
  <div className="calculator__display">
    {this.state.text}
    <Button value="Click Me" onClick={this.clicked} />
  </div>
);
}
```

Then the Button can be updated to just:

```
class Button extends Component {
render() {
  return (
  <div className="calculator__button" onClick={() => this.props.onClick()}>
    {this.props.value}
  </div>
  );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html),
like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Display from '../Display/Display.js';

class Button extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.myRef = React.createRef();
    }

    clicked(e) {
        this.myRef.current.clicked();
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <Display ref={this.myRef}/>
            <div className="calculator__button" onClick={() =>
                this.clicked(this.props.value)}>
                {this.props.value}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Button;
```